# I want to know if I need airport transit visa

Tags: airports, transit-visas, netherlands, klm

I have a Ugandan passport and i will be traveling from Dubai to Mexico via armsterdam very soon. So do I need a transit visa

Comment: No. [Here](https://www.government.nl/binaries/government/documents/forms/2015/11/26/list-of-airport-transit-visa-countries/nationals-of-the-following-countries-need-an-airport-transit-visa-to-change-aircraft-at-an-airport-in-a-schengen-country.pdf) is the relevant list for the Netherlands.

Answer (score 3):

Please enter your traveller, destination, and transit information in [Timatic](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/vendors/default.aspx?i=TIMATIC) and it will tell you if a visa is required for transfer through the Netherlands.

Enter your personal information here: https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/vendors/default.aspx?i=TIMATIC

Illustration (may **not** be accurate for yourself):

[image]

Results:

[image]